# Javascript to Jquery convertion, removing first child every iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rewriting some old projects with Jquery to learn it better, I managed to do everything except for this while loop. It should loop through a container of divs and remove the first child every time.

```
var calendarModel = {
    siteContainer: $('#calendar-container')
}

while (calendarModel.siteContainer.firstChild) {
    calendarModel.siteContainer.removeChild(calendarModel.siteContainer.firstChild);
}
```

My first (horrible) attempt yielded no result except for an infinite loop:

```
var firstDiv = $('div:first-child', calendarModel.siteContainer);

while (firstDiv) {
    firstDiv.remove();
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
var firstDiv = $('div:first-child', calendarModel.siteContainer);

while (calendarModel.siteContainer.firstDiv) {
    calendarModel.siteContainer.firstDiv.remove();
}
```

Which was even worse cuz then it doesn't even enter the loop.

I also tried without the loop to see if it removed anything at all:

```
var firstDiv = $('div:first-child', calendarModel.siteContainer);
    firstDiv.remove();
```

However, it didn't. I'm really stuck so I'd appreciate some help on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post sample markup?

Comment: @JamesHill jsFiddle you mean?

Comment: Fiddle, or just in the question. Obviously...fiddle is better :)

Comment: Why not: `calendarModel.siteContainer.empty();` ?

Comment: Why convert working JS code to jQuery? You're just adding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @sixfingeredman, he stated why he was doing it in the question (and it's a good reason). Did you read the question?

Comment: @JamesHill: Yes, I did read that. The question still stands. Seems like a waste to burden working code with the overhead of a library. I could see it on a new project where it's actually needed. Seems like a more productive way to learn.

Comment: @sixfingeredman I learn better this way plus my lack of imagination for new projects make it less productive in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dangerous with jQuery to remove nodes using the native api since it can cause memory leaks.

Instead use a jQuery method so that data is cleaned up.

```
calendarModel.siteContainer.children().remove();
```

Comment: You're welcome. There are several ways to do this. If there are text nodes that need to go, then you could use `.contents()` instead of `.children()`. Or just use `.empty()` as the comment above stated.

Comment: Is there a difference in terms of execution time for .empty() vs .children().remove()? Which would you recommend?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: Probably should do `.empty()` if you want to get rid of all of the content, but jQuery is already going to be quite slow. If you need better performance, then you'd probably need to reduce or eliminate jQuery. If not, then don't worry about it until you actually have a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Loops have to have a test condition in them. They loop through until that test condition is no longer true. So assuming your `firstDiv` selector has an array of div's

```
var i = 0;
while(firstDiv.length > i){
   console.log(firstDiv[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `> i`.

Comment: If `.length` is `10` and `i` is `0`, then what is the result of `10 < 0`? Since `i` starts at `0` and you increment it, you want it to run as long as `firstDiv.length > i`